# Rolebinding wasn't that i expected

Tags: kubernetes

I created a clusterrole of all verbs for deployment and pod.

> kubectl create clusterrole pipeline-manager --verb create,delete,update,list,get --resource deployments,pods

And i create a ServiceAccount pipeline on test namespace.

> kubectl create sa pipeline -n test

I bound serviceaccount and clusterrole on test namespace.

> kubectl create rolebinding pipeline-resources-role --clusterrole=pipeline-manager --serviceaccount=test:pipeline -n test

When i tested if it works well, the result was not what i expected.

```
# Yes expected
k auth can-i list deployments --as system:serviceaccount:test:pipeline -n test => result : yes
k auth can-i list pods --as system:serviceaccount:test:pipeline -n test => result : no
```

I want to know what i know wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It works.

I did edit clusterrole as wrong way after creating.

Don't mind this article.